# Android get bitmap from camera, scale canvas to bitmap size and save bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, camera, scale

I let users to choose image resolution, for example 4096x3024px then get that mutable bitmap from the stream then send it to surfaceview and create another canvas, which is to be used to scale from screen size to bitmap size.

When i scale this canvas up image is not upscaled correctly. I tried creating a matrix scaled it up from a center pivot but still no result.

This where i get the bitmap from camera preview and draw to canvas used for scaling and saving

```
    public Bitmap mergeImageAndCanvas(Bitmap bitmap) {

    // DRAW TO Canvas created in constructor
    canvasImage.setBitmap(bitmap);
    render(canvasImage, true);
    canvasImage.setBitmap(null);
    System.out.println("Canvas " + canvas.getWidth() + ", height " + canvas.getHeight());

    return bitmap;
}
```

Here i upScale and try to center image to maintain exact position of texts and lines i draw

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Surfaceview surfaceChanged() width " +
    // width + ", height" + height,
    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    bitmapWitdh = photoHandler.photoWidth;
    bitmapHeight = photoHandler.photoHeight;
    canvasWidth = width;
    ratioX = (float) canvasWidth / 1280;
    canvasHeight = height;
    scaleX = ((float) bitmapWitdh) / (float) canvasWidth;
    scaleY = ((float) bitmapHeight) / (float) canvasHeight;
    float middleX = bitmapWitdh / 2.0f;
    float middleY = bitmapHeight / 2.0f;
    scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    // scaleMatrix.preScale(scaleX, scaleY);
    scaleMatrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY, middleX, middleY);
    // scaleMatrix.postTranslate(-(bitmapWitdh) / 2, -(bitmapHeight) / 2);
    // scaleMatrix.setTranslate(300, 300);
    canvasImage.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
}
```

Here is the what i wish to achive after upscale(This is what user sees on screen with resolution 1280x720) [Image Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lrot.jpg)

This what user gets(image resolution 2560x1920) [Final image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIB1H.jpg)

Comment: `then get that mutable bitmap from the stream`. Sorry, you go to quick. From which stream? From a camera?

Comment: I have no problem getting bitmap from camera. Problem starts after getting it and setting it as bitmap for the canvas.

Yes get bitmap from data from onPictureTaken method. Use inMutable option to make it suitable for drawing onto it via canvas. But resolution transfromation is where i fail.

Comment: I get bitmap with bigger dimensions, from camera,  than canvas  which lines text are drawn onto. I upscale canvas to match bitmap dimension but text and drawing positions are not where they suppossed to be.

Comment: `Yes get bitmap from data from onPictureTaken method`. `data` contains a jpg image. You are converting that your self to a Bitmap i suppose. You are not getting a bitmap from camera as you tell in the subject of this post. Now where is that stream you are talking about?

Comment: If the original bitmap (from data) is 4096x3024 you want to resize it to 1280x720 but you get 2560x1920 ? I cannot follow you. WHat exactly is the problem?

Comment: I said it's an example. I get bitmap whatever the resolution of the camera size is selected. I draw lines to screen, my screen is 1280x720px, then upscale canvas to original image dimensions.  bitmapWitdh = photoHandler.photoWidth is the width of the bitmap you get from inputstream via BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);

Comment: I want to scale canvas  from 1280x720 to 2560x1920  for instance but these values are dynamic. If you have device with 1920x1080 and selected camera size 4000x3000, then i want to scale from 1920x1080 to 4000x3000 with correct scaling and positions of text and drawings.

Comment: Why is it that you want to upscale a canvas instead of downscaling a bitmap?

Comment: But what is the problem exactly? Cannot a canvas of 4000x3000 be made?

Comment: Yes, it can be made but you display something on screen, right? That screen may not have the 4000x3000 resolution. Because of that you need to upscale canvas while saving the image.

For example, LibGDX does this using Viewports, but you need to upscale it via matrix transformation if you are using canvas . I'm asking how to transform it correctly and keep proportions intact

Comment: t's navigation and surveying app that let's users to choose captured image resolution. If user wants to capture a view with higher resolution than device screen has, i have to upscale what is drawn on screen to camera resolution. I tried to translate and scale canvas matrix but i made some mistakes i quess. 

Posted images show what it supposed to look like and how it looks like. 
Green buttons are not drawn to canvas, so ignore them.

Comment: It is all very interesting. Am experimenting with it. At the moment surfaceChanged() comes before onPictureTaken(). So if that happens with you too then how do you use the result 'canvasImage`of onPictureTaken() in surfaceChanged()?

Comment: These are basics for Augmented Reality apps. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thraciansoftware.diopthrace This is the app if you want to take look at it. There is also another problem, i designed it using 1280x720 phone, if you use a device with higher resolution, what is displayed on screen is also not correct.

You capture image via pushing capture button. So, it's nearly impossible for app to invoke pictureTaken() before surfaceChanged().

it's in strictly landscape mode, if you don't pause the app sufraceChanged() is called only once, but you can capture image at will.

Comment: The `render` function is unclear. And you print `System.out.println("Canvas " + canvas.getWidth() + ", height " + canvas.getHeight());` and not System.out.println("Canvas " + canvasImage.getWidth() + ", height " + canvasImage.getHeight());

Comment: It's probably because i was drawing onto canvas of SurfaceView before creating this current canvas, canvasImage for only saving image. It's

How can i post a java file? It would be better if you had looked into the entire class itself. I cannot paste it here.

Comment: Indeed. Try http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Here is the full class http://pastebin.com/XLpUM87j

Comment: Ok. Think i can try that out without classes SensorUtilizer and LocationActivity. But not without Reticle and PhotoHandler i think. So if you still need help please post them too.

Comment: I finally solved what was wrong. It was due to racing conditions between threads that using different canvases with different dimensions. Culprit is `setTextPositions(canvas);` method, i invoked it only at surfaceChanged() and what causing wrong matrix computation is solved.

Comment: Ok. Then we are done.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your efforts. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to scale canvas for any resolution is just to scale it with `Canvas.setScale()` method. Matrix scaling is applied from origin, which is (0,0),top- left of the screen by default, it converts canvas dimension to any other dimension via scaleX and scaleY factors you get from dividing desired resolution(dimensions of the captured image from camera) by current resolution(device resolution) width and height.

It's basically matching captured image and device's screen dimensions.